# Inserting rows and columns into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to insert multiple rows and columns into a `NumPy` array.

If I have a square array of length `n_a`, e.g.: `n_a = 3`

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

and I would like to get a new array with size `n_b`, which contains array `a` and `zeros` (or any other `1D` array of length `n_b`) on certain rows and columns with indices, e.g.

```
index = [1, 3]
```

so `n_b = n_a + len(index)`. Then the new array is:

```
b = np.array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [4, 0, 5, 0, 6],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [7, 0, 8, 0, 9]])
```

My question is, how to do this efficiently, with the assumption that by bigger arrays `n_a` is much larger than `len(index)`.

**EDIT**

The results for:

```
import numpy as np
import random

n_a = 5000
n_index = 100

a=np.random.rand(n_a, n_a)
index = random.sample(range(n_a), n_index)
```

Warren Weckesser's solution: 0.208 s

wim's solution: 0.980 s

Ashwini Chaudhary's solution: 0.955 s

Thank you to all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  It has some overlap with @wim's answer, but it uses index broadcasting to copy `a` into `b` with a single assignment.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])

index = [1, 3]
n_b = a.shape[0] + len(index)

not_index = np.array([k for k in range(n_b) if k not in index])

b = np.zeros((n_b, n_b), dtype=a.dtype)
b[not_index.reshape(-1,1), not_index] = a
```

Comment: yes, good!  this is the best way and that's what I was _trying_ to do with `b[not_index,:][:,not_index] = a` (which doesn't work).  your method should be approx twice as fast as mine.

Comment: I don't know how it will affect speed, but I propose generating the not_index array using sets instead of a list comprehension:

`index = {1, 3}`

`n_b = a.shape[0] + len(index) # this remains the same`

`not_index = np.array(list( set(range(n_b)) - index))`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by applying two `numpy.insert` calls on `a`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
>>> indices = np.array([1, 3])
>>> i = indices - np.arange(len(indices))
>>> np.insert(np.insert(a, i, 0, axis=1), i, 0, axis=0)
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 5, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [7, 0, 8, 0, 9]])
```

Comment: This works, however I am looking for a more general anwser on what to do after an empty array is created (arr[::2, ::2] = a works for this case only).

Comment: For this 3x3 size, this solution is 5-10 times slower.  But with a 100x100 matrix, it is faster than the other 2 (2x).  Internally `insert` uses the build a large filled matrix, and then populates it with the old data.  So the speed difference must come (mostly) from operating first on rows and then columns.

Comment: I posted the comparison of the anwser's above. The solution from @Warren Weckesser is still faster.

Comment: -(-1)  I stand corrected, I thought `np.insert` would have to shift a lot of data but it seems it's implemented better than I've assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Since fancy indexing returns a copy instead of a view,
I can only think how to do it in a two-step process.  Maybe a numpy wizard knows a better way...

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])

index = [1, 3]
n = a.shape[0]
N = n + len(index)

non_index = [x for x in xrange(N) if x not in index]

b = np.zeros((N,n), a.dtype)
b[non_index] = a

a = np.zeros((N,N), a.dtype)
a[:, non_index] = b
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just [Slice/splice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)?  This has zero loops or *for* statements.

```
xlen = a.shape[1]
ylen = a.shape[0]
b = np.zeros((ylen * 2 - ylen % 2, xlen * 2 - xlen % 2))  #accomodates both odd and even shapes
b[0::2,0::2] = a
```